# Commit changes to Group View even after Activity Reload

Tags: java, android

I have a method to add items to a `Group View`:

```
void addItem(String name,String quantity,String value,ViewGroup view_group,int index)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)myAct.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.request_object_list, null);

        ((TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.object_name)).setText(name);

        ((TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.object_quantity)).setText(quantity);

        ImageButton botaoAdd = ((ImageButton)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.addButton));
        ImageButton botaoSubtract = ((ImageButton)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.subtractButton));

        buttons.put(botaoAdd, ((TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.object_quantity)));
        buttons.put(botaoSubtract, ((TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.object_quantity)));

        botaoAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ImageButton botao = (ImageButton)arg0;

                TextView textView = buttons.get(botao);

                Integer quantidade = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());

                quantidade++;

                textView.setText(quantidade.toString());
            }
        });

        botaoSubtract.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ImageButton botao = (ImageButton)arg0;

                TextView textView = buttons.get(botao);

                Integer quantidade = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());

                if(quantidade != 1)
                    quantidade--;

                textView.setText(quantidade.toString());
            }
        });

        ((TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.object_value)).setText(value);
        (itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.select_check)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        (itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.select_check)).setId(index);

        view_group.addView(itemLayout);
    }
```

As you can see I have 2 buttons which can make modifications to their respective items on the `Group View`. Although After reloading the `Activity`, the items of the Group View are exactly with the same values from when they were initially added. How can I commit the changes?

Comment: Are there going to be a dynamic number of buttons added or will there always be 2 buttons?

Comment: In that case, you could just include the buttons in the layout and keep them hidden. You can toggle the visibility as needed.

Comment: No, you misunderstood my problem. I have an input on my interface which can modify the items which are inside the Group View. If I change the Activity and then change back again, all the modifications that have been made to those items will not be there.

Comment: Mmm... Apologies. Edit: Incorrect Information